Python -> Java migration: Java Kafka consumer Received fatal alert: bad_certificate when migrating from Python to Java
I have working Python Kafka consumer, and I'm trying to migrate it to Java(Spring) one. However I'm stuck in the process, I can't connect to bootstrap server - my consumer is failing at the stage of SSL cert exchange? I'm getting error:
Received fatal alert: bad_certificate

I've tried many options, like I created my dedicated JKS containing multiple certs (Certs are self issues I believe, internally in the company) with all certs both exported from browser or from the working Python consumer and nothing works. I've tried also putting those certs in default cacerts store, still getting the same error (previously before adding those certs I had different error). I've tried creating custom PKCS12 keystore providing PEM cert, .key file and CA file from Python config that I have, however this doesn't work neither.
I'm basically out of the options I can think of right now.
    ssl_certificate_location = os.getenv('SSL_CERTIFICATE_LOCATION', './cert/mycert.pem')
    ssl_key_location = os.getenv('SSL_KEY_LOCATION', './cert/mycert_pass.key')
    ssl_key_password = os.getenv('SSL_KEY_PASSWORD', 'mypass')
    ssl_ca_location = os.getenv('SSL_CA_LOCATION', './cert/my_ca.crt')
    consumer_conf = {'bootstrap.servers':bootstrap_servers,
                         'client.id':'my-listener',
                         'group.id':'my-listener',
                         'auto.offset.reset':'earliest',
                         'security.protocol':'SSL',
                         'max.poll.interval.ms':1200000,
                         'ssl.certificate.location':ssl_certificate_location,
                         'ssl.key.location':ssl_key_location,
                         'ssl.key.password':ssl_key_password,
                         'ssl.ca.location':ssl_ca_location,
                         }

And there's my spring config related to kafka:
spring:
    kafka:
        bootstrap-servers: kafka_url:9092
        consumer:
            key-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
            value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
        properties:
            auto:
                register:
                    schemas: true
            security:
                protocol: SSL
            spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
            spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
        ssl:
            key-password: mypass
            key-store-location: classpath:kafka_cert.jks
            key-store-password: mypass

My kafka_cert.jks contains multiple certificates (I've tried multiple of our self signed certs) and one Key par, the same one that was used in Python.

The issue is that certificate that has been offered is defective in some way. Without actual certificate details it will be hard to determine what the problem is.

Perhaps you could check out this github thread https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/943
